# Cannot perform proper view paging in Android GalleryView

Tags: android, android-gallery

I'm trying to use Android GalleryView to implement a view that can scroll horizontally as well as vertically, similar to the Google Music application. However, if I place a ListView inside a GalleryView, the ListView seems to steal all touch events and I'm unable to scroll horizontally on a GalleryView. What am I doing wrong? Is this the best approach? Does anyone have any other suggestions? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do not use a GalleryView for paging views. Furthermore, having a ListView inside a GalleryView is never recommended.

Instead use the ViewPager that's available as part of the Android Compatibility Package. I think that's more relevant to what you're trying to achieve. Here's a detailed article on ViewPager:

http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/08/horizontal-view-swiping-with-viewpager.html